# How to migrate to git an SVN repository with tags created with eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, subversive

I am trying to migrate my repository from SVN to git but I experience issues due to the layout (mainly how tags have been created).
This is the SVN layout:

```
svn+ssh://myserver/myproject/
    branches/
    tags/
        myproject_0.0.1/
            <project content> (tag created with command line svn)
        myproject_0.0.2/
            myproject/
                <project content> (tag created with eclipse IDE svn plugin)
        ...
        <many other tags of both types>
    trunk/
        myproject/
            <project content>
```

Using git svn clone I get the following:

```
myproject/
    myproject/
        <project content>
    .git/ (git repo)
```

This is not the standard layout of a git project, which I would like to have. The same applies to tags created with eclipse IDE. I would like to have the following, for both master and tags.

```
myproject/
    <checked out project content>
    .git/ (git repo)
```

**Is there a way to do this migration properly?** Having this mismatches really messes up comparison between versions, checkouts, etc.

Comment: What exactly was your [`git svn clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) command line? Did you use the `--stdlayout` option? I don't think it matters what tool you used to create the tags.

Comment: I used:
git svn clone svn+ssh://myserver/myproject/ --trunk=trunk/myproject --tags=tags --branches=branches

Answer (score 1):

It definitely can be done with [SubGit](https://subgit.com), only you would need to change the mapping layout for it. For your case, the following should work:

```
[svn]
    url = svn+ssh://myserver/myproject/
    trunk = trunk/myproject:refs/heads/master
    tags = tags/myproject_0.0.1:refs/tags/myproject_0.0.1
    tags = tags/myproject_0.0.2/myproject:refs/tags/myproject_0.0.2
    …
```

The rest tags should be set in the same way; and with this configuration, the project content will reside right in the root of a branch in Git. SubGit is free for one-time import, so there's no difference with git svn in that matter.